# Measuring Documentation Coverage with Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I wanted to ask if there are any features (or add-ons) for Doxygen to measure the documentation coverage via command line. I already know that I can set up Doxygen to write undocumented elements as warnings into a log file, but to fully evaluate the documentation coverage from that, I'd need to write my own warning log parser. Was something like this done already or is there an even easier way I couldn't find? Is there any add-on I could check out for this?
Thank you.

Comment: You want an output that says `95% of all functions are documentes`. Did i get that right?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know anything that can give documentation coverage for doxygen, but a quick search gives 2 interesting results : https://github.com/alobbs/doxy-coverage (require xml output for doxygen) and http://jessevdk.github.io/cldoc/ (alternative for c++ projects?)

Answer (score 2):

There is [coverxygen](https://github.com/psycofdj/coverxygen) which is using the same idea as alobbs/doxy-coverage (uses xml output of Doxygen) but provides more options (for example, filter by access specifier).

Disclaimer: I am contributing to that project.

Comment: +1 for a CLI solution and a program outputting JSON and YAML, making possible to parse that. I don't understand why it's score is zero, is it because the program is licensed under GPLv3?